# Trying to play mp3 ActivityNotFoundException on certain devices

Tags: android

I'm getting crash reports from a Galaxy Ace device trying to play mp3 files.

The audio from the server will always come as mp3.

Here's my code:

```
Intent intentaudio = new Intent();
intentaudio.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentaudio.setDataAndType(URL_OF_MY_MP3_FILE, "audio/mp3");
```

Here's the exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {
  act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://mymediaserver.com/8/0_rwtel7ii.mp3 typ=audio/mp3 }
```

What is wrong with that? All devices are supposed to be able to play mp3 by default, no?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently some devices don't have an activity that can handle playing mp3 files. Those devices should be able to play mp3 files, but there is no activity to handle the intent. You gotta write one yourself and set the intent-filter to say your activity can handle playing mp3.

Try this and see if there is a music player.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this error if your device doesn't have an app that supports this format. So, I recommend you surround this code with a *try/catch*.