# No Activity found to handle Intent, at audio player open

Tags: android, android-intent

This code works ok in a lot of devices.

But I have some report of users of some devices:

> Xperia L (C2104)  1   3,4% Droid Ultra (obake)    1   3,4% Droid MAXX
>   (obake-maxx)  2   6,9% Moto E (condor_cdma)   1   3,4% Moto G (falcon_umts)
>     2   6,9% MOTO E (condor_umts)   2   6,9% HUAWEI H881C (hwh881c)     1   3,4%
>   Galaxy Tab3 7.0 (lt02ltespr)  1   3,4% Nexus 4 (mako)     1   3,4% Hydro EDGE
>   (C5215)   2   6,9% Galaxy Young2 (young2nfc3g)    1   3,4% Galaxy Core Prime
>   (cprimeltemtr)    1   3,4% Xperia Z2 (D6503)  1   3,4% Z667 (demi)    1   3,4%
>   LG Power (y50c)   3   10,3% Xperia tipo (ST21a)   3   10,3% Galaxy Grand
>   Prime (grandprimelteaio)  1   3,4% Moto G (falcon_cdma)   4   13,8%

In this piece of code to play audio in device audio player:

```
final File file = new File(mFileName);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/mpeg"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/MyAudioFiles/file.mp3 typ=audio/mpeg }

This means that this devices don´t have a default audio player installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to start the activity, it might be that the mimetype you provide is not being handled correctly.

```
try
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(mFileName); 
    String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
    String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimetype);
    startActivity(intent);
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Perhaps you also need to have the `WRITE` and `READ` external permissions (in case a user installs your app on the sd card), but I am not sure about this, it should not be needed I think.

Seems to be a duplicate of this one though: [Trying to play mp3 ActivityNotFoundException on certain devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346716/trying-to-play-mp3-activitynotfoundexception-on-certain-devices)